# Does fgets() move the file pointer?

Tags: c, file, pointers, fgets

Does the `fgets()` function move the file pointer automatically to the position till the parameter of the size mentioned by me?

for example:

the content of the file p.txt is `" I am a good boy "`. After using `fgets(a, 5, fp1)`
does the file pointer move 5 positions ahead?

Comment: The `FILE*` is not modified by `fgets()`. The *file offset* may be (if the file is seekable).

Comment: I wonder why you ask. Have you some code that indicates otherwise? There must be some background for this question. Please explain.

Comment: @SamS - why would you think a question about `fgets()` is a duplicate of a question about `fread()`?

Comment: the reason is i want to copy one file to the other . so the question that arose in my mind that if the pointer does not move , the string variable in my fgets() argument will have the same string .

Comment: @ArkaPravaPaul - The file position indicator **is** changed when doing `fgets`. Successive `fgets` will **not** return the same data. No problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> after using fgets(a,5,fp1) does the file pointer move 5 positions ahead ?

The pointer `fp1` is not affected by the `fgets` call (or any other `stdio` I/O routine); The `FILE` object that `fp1` points to will be updated to reflect the new file position, but the pointer itself does not change.

Comment: Could you recommend me some C references/books ? .. I could not find about this in any particular book .

Comment: @ArkaPravaPaul:  I've been using Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com) since the late '80s (currently 5th edition, covers up through C99).  I've also heard good things about King's [C Programming: A Modern. Approach](http://knking.com/books/c/), although I don't have personal experience with it.  And you should bookmark the latest [online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C language standard.

Comment: This is the most crucial detail about the function and no cpp reference, man page or website states the basic fact that there's a file position that's incremented, they just make you work it out for yourself – it's obvious from the output, and the fact the function would be useless without it because there's no offset parameter so you'd always be reading from the start of the file and wouldn't be able to read past a new line. I don't know why these sites don't state it explicitly, then questions like this wouldn't be asked

Comment: @LewisKelsey: Because a stream doesn't have to be tied to a file, and because it's a ridiculously low-level detail that the `stdio` library was explicitly designed to hide from you.  You call `fgets`, magic happens, and data appears in the target buffer.

Answer (score 3):

The file pointer is not modified by the `fgets` function.

However, the file offset is incremented by the number of bytes *actually* read.

Comment: You should emphasize that "the number of bytes read" is NOT equal to the second argument to `fgets`; it will be *at most* one less than that value, and may be smaller (if you hit EOF or a newline or read error).